# getting a csv file from a remote select query

Tags: windows, postgresql, database

I have a client windows host that would like to connect to a Postgres database, issue a select query and return that query to the windows host a CSV file.

I do know that Postgres has a copy command that will work.

```
copy (SELECT * from foo) To '/tmp/forDavid.csv' with CSV DELIMITER ',';
```

And this customer will be accessing this SELECT query daily. The client windows host and the Postgres database is on an internal network.

I want to avoid using PHPMyAdmin because he is not savvy, I want this to be as simple as possible. I do know Perl but that would involve installing Perl on client windows host which I don't want to do.

What would be the easiest solution for this task?

Comment: I google'd a bit, and found that there are Powershell modules or ODBC drivers that should work with Powershell. Would either of those work for you?

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do here is use the `COPY ... TO STDOUT` form of COPY and then capture the output and then capture the output on your local system or app and write that to your local file.  A simple example using psql from the command line (not using psql's `\copy` stuff and no need to set the delimiter to a comma since that's the default for CSV output):

`psql -U ejones -h remote_host.com -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM foo) TO STDOUT CSV;" somedb > /tmp/forDavid.csv`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-copy.html